# Using recursive grep on multiple group of words, and output them in different text files

Tags: grep, tee

I try to figure out a way to use recursive `grep` on a group of words, and output the results in different textfiles.

My thought was I can do this in my case:

```
grep -r -A 2 -B 2 --include={LIST}.{txt,log} -e "DATA1\|DATA1.5" -e "DATA2\|DATA2.5" -e "DATA3\|DATA3.5" | tee >(grep -e "DATA1\|DATA1.5" > output1.txt) | tee >(grep -e "DATA2\|DATA2.5" > output2.txt) | tee >(grep -e "DATA3\|DATA3.5" > output3.txt)
```

For some reason I get

```
tee: unknown option -- e
```

For my understanding because I use `(`, it is `grep` that should handle the option `-e` and and not `tee`.

Small note: I'm using CygWin on Windows; that's why you see I'm using double quotes.

Comment: the `tee` part seems to work for me. does the shell in Cygwin support process substitution (the `>( ... )` thing)? You might want to test if some simpler command works.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use Bash syntax, but the error message suggests that your shell isn't Bash. Are you trying to do this in CMD?

Comment: hmm yeah seems to be you're right. For some reason cmd vs cygwin have a different interpretation. but yes I ran it in CMD